# factorise the expression (1+a)-(1-a)x^{2}

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to factorise the expression $(1+a)-(1-a)x^2$ I know the answer is $1-\frac{1-a}{1+a}x^2$
Someone can help me. I  tried using several methods by until the moment without result.

Answer (score 0):

That's not really a factorization. If you're just trying to solve $$(1+a)-(1-a)x^2=0$$then surely you can divide by $1+a$ (assuming $a\neq -1$) to arrive at $$1-\frac{1-a}{1+a}x^2=0$$If you actually want to factor the expression on the left you can use the "difference of squares" method by writing $$\frac{1-a}{1+a}=\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-a}{1+a}}\right)^2$$assuming $\frac{1-a}{1+a}>0$.

Answer (score 0):

It's not true that
$$(1+a) - (1-a)x^2=1 - {\small{\frac{1-a}{1+a}}}x^2$$

What is true, assuming $a \ne -1,\;$is
$$(1+a) - (1-a)x^2=(1+a)\left(1 - {\small{\frac{1-a}{1+a}}}x^2\right)$$
Note:$\;$It's a *forced* factorization. There's no good reason to factor out the expression $(1+a)$, but if one chooses to do so, the above is what you get.

I suspect you've misstated the actual problem.